# Neopixel strip animation toggle problems

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have a strip of Neopixels that I'm using for underglow on my bed. Recently, I decided to add a sound sensor so that I can clap once to toggle the light animations I'm using either on or off. Now I'm just running into trouble getting my code to work. I can turn the lights on but I can't clap again to turn them off. What I suspect may be the problem is the fact that I only give the condition for the light animation to be turned off at the end of the while loop that I use to run the light animations, however, I have no idea what I can do to fix that. Can somebody help me on this?

```cpp
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#ifdef __AVR__
#include <avr/power.h>
#endif
#define PIN 6

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(60, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
int soundSensor = 2;
int LED = 13;


void setup() 
{

// This is for Trinket 5V 16MHz, you can remove these three lines if you are not using a Trinket
  #if defined (__AVR_ATtiny85__)
    if (F_CPU == 16000000) clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);
  #endif
  // End of trinket special code

  strip.begin();
  strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
  pinMode (soundSensor, INPUT);
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  int toggle = 0;
  int statusSensor = digitalRead (soundSensor);

  if (statusSensor == 1 && toggle == 0)
  {
    toggle= 1;
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    //statusSensor = 0;
    statusSensor = digitalRead (soundSensor);
  }

    //NEOPIXEL CODE:
  while (toggle == 1)
  {
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);
  colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 0, 0), 50);     // Red
  colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 255, 0), 50);     // Green
  colorWipe(strip.Color(255,255,255), 50);   //White
  colorWipe(strip.Color(255,255,255), 50);
  colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 255), 50); // Blue
  rainbow(20);
  rainbowCycle(20);
  if(statusSensor == 1){
    toggle = 0;
  }
  }

  if (statusSensor == 1 && toggle == 1)
  {
    toggle = 0;
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  }


}


//NEOPIXEL Functions:
void colorWipe(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
  for(uint16_t i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}

void rainbow(uint8_t wait) {
  uint16_t i, j;

  for(j=0; j<256; j++) {
    for(i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, Wheel((i+j) & 255));
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}

// Slightly different, this makes the rainbow equally distributed throughout
void rainbowCycle(uint8_t wait) {
  uint16_t i, j;

  for(j=0; j<256*5; j++) { // 5 cycles of all colors on wheel
    for(i=0; i< strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, Wheel(((i * 256 / strip.numPixels()) + j) & 255));
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}

uint32_t Wheel(byte WheelPos) {
  WheelPos = 255 - WheelPos;
  if(WheelPos < 85) {
    return strip.Color(255 - WheelPos * 3, 0, WheelPos * 3);
  }
  if(WheelPos < 170) {
    WheelPos -= 85;
    return strip.Color(0, WheelPos * 3, 255 - WheelPos * 3);
  }
  WheelPos -= 170;
  return strip.Color(WheelPos * 3, 255 - WheelPos * 3, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set toggle to 0, you don't write any colors to the neo-pixel strip. So they will just be left in whatever state they were in. You can fix this by just setting them all to "black" (i.e. off) when you set the toggle to zero:

```
if(statusSensor == 1) {
    toggle = 0;
    for(uint16_t i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
       strip.setPixelColor(strip.Color(0,0,0));
    }
    strip.show();
}
```

You don't need any delay here if you just want them to turn out straight away, but perhaps you could make them fade down?